# CakePHP: habtm with join table having an extra field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

I am generating model tables with cake bake utility, and I am facing a strange situation.

I have these tables:

- `product(id_product)`
- `guest(id_guest)`
- `product_guest(product, guest, amount)`

where `product_guest` table keep trace of what product a guest bought, and the amount of product bought.

Now, with HABTM relationship on cake bake, I can only specify relation between tables product and guest, but there's no trace of the `amount` field.

How can I map this situation correctly to retrieve and add `amount` too?

Comment: OP , even care to check answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, HABTM is not the correct association to use. You should be using the [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) association.

The fundamental change is that you need a third model based on your product_guest table.

Create these relationships:

- Product hasMany ProductGuest
- Guest hasMany ProductGuest
- ProductGuest belongsTo Product
- ProductGuest belongsTo Guest

Comment: so i can use HABTM when i don't have any extra fields inside join table, and i necessary need to use hasMany and belongsTo when i have it?

Comment: @giozh - correct: Use HABTM when the join table has **only** the keys to the other tables _(and its primary key)_. When the join table has additional columns, use the hasMany and belongsTo.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong table structure 1st of all

You should have

```
guests : id , user_name , password
```

This is the guest who will purchase product . This is master table.

```
products : id , product_name , description
```

This is your product table with details regarding to products like description etc. This is master table.

```
orders -> id , amount , user_id
```

Here order is a table with details such as who bought product and price. This is master table.

Then one order can have many Items so

```
orders_products ->  order_id , product_id
```

Now this will contain order id and which product was included as foreign key. This is Child table which contains Foreign keys of product and order.

Here orders_products  is HABTM with products And orders as

One order can contain multiple products.And one product can be part of multiple orders. Does it make sense  ?